# iOS: IncompleteSignatureException when calling AWS Amplify GET

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, http-status-code-403

I'm having an issue where I'm unable to do a GET Request to an AWS Amplify API even after seemingly configuring everything properly. Currently I'm using AWSMobileClient and the iOS Amplify SDK to develop an app:

```
AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().getTokens { (tokens, err) in
    NSLog("tokens: \(tokens.debugDescription)")
    NSLog("tokens: \(tokens!.idToken!.claims.debugDescription)")
    self.doInvokeAPI(token: tokens!.idToken!.tokenString!)
}

//...

func doInvokeAPI(token: String) {
    let headerParameters = [
                "Authorization" : token,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            ]
    
    let queryParams = ["response" : "true"]
    let request = RESTRequest(apiName: <ENDPOINT_NAME>, path: <PATH>, headers: headerParameters, queryParameters: queryParams, body: nil)
    
    Amplify.API.get(request: request, listener: responseCallBack)

    
}
```

When I call Amplify.API.get(), I'm constantly getting a 403 Error, and after creating some helper functions (responseCallBack) to log the HTTP response, I'm receiving this, which shows it's an IncompleteSignatureException:

```
HTTP:  <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x283a580a0> { URL: <my-endpoint-url>/<my-path>?response=true } { Status Code: 403, Headers {
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =     (
    "*"
);
"Content-Length" =     (
    1158
);
"Content-Type" =     (
    "application/json"
);
Date =     (
    "Fri, 23 Oct 2020 21:22:06 GMT"
);
"access-control-allow-headers" =     (
    "*"
);
"x-amzn-errortype" =     (
    IncompleteSignatureException
);
"x-cache" =     (
    "Error from cloudfront"
);
```

} }

My amplifyconfiguration.json file looks like this:

```
{
"api": {
    "plugins": {
        "awsAPIPlugin": {
            <MY_ENDPOINT_NAME>: {
                "endpointType": "REST",
                "endpoint": <MY_ENDPOINT_URL>,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
            },
            <MY_OTHER_ENDPOINT_NAME>: {
                "endpointType": "REST",
                "endpoint": <MY_ENDPOINT_URL>,
                "region": "us-west-2",
                "authorizationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
            }
        }
    },
},

"auth": {
        "plugins": {
            "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": {
                "IdentityManager": {
                    "Default": {}
                },
                "CredentialsProvider": {
                    "CognitoIdentity": {
                        "Default": {
                          "PoolId": <IDENTITY_POOL_ID>,
                          "Region": "us-west-2"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "CognitoUserPool": {
                  "Default": {
                    "PoolId": <USER_POOL_ID>,
                    "AppClientId": <APP_CLIENT_ID>,
                    "Region": "us-west-2"
                  }
                },
            }
        }
    },
```

}

And my awsconfiguration.json looks like this:

```
 {
  "UserAgent": "aws-amplify/cli",
  "Version": "1.0.5",
  "IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
  },
  "CredentialsProvider": {
    "CognitoIdentity": {
      "Default": {
        "PoolId": <IDENTITY_USER_POOL_ID>,
        "Region": "us-west-2"
      }
    }
  },
  "CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
      "PoolId": <USER_POOL_ID>,
      "AppClientId": <APP_CLIENT_ID>,
      "Region": "us-west-2"
    }
  }
}
```

I can authenticate into my app (Auth.signIn() works) and Amplify.configure() in AppDelegate.swift doesn't seem to run into issues, since no errors occur when attempting to configure, so it looks like it passes that point. But when I try to call the API, I receive this error. I include the JWT token in the Authorization header when making the request, and have triple checked that I do not have typos. Does anyone have an idea as to why I cannot call the API?